# Check if bearer token is jwt or not

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I have two types of tokens coming in for a http request. One has a JWT token in the authorization header and other has a fixed length oauth token.
Based on the type of token, I want to perform some action. How do I differentiate them?

I have tried

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      String pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\\.^[A-Za-z0-9-_.+/=]*$";
      String line="eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9tbD.epxpstvGdW8TC3G8zg4B6rUYAOvfzdceoH48wgRQ";
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {  //is jwt
         System.out.println("jwt token");
      }else {
         System.out.println("NOt jwt");
      }
    }
}
```

but this is not working as expected. Is there any library which does this? Or can we modify the above regex?

Comment: Is your app responsible for generating tokens?

Comment: Note that certain characters like `.` or `-` in a character class have special meaning in a regular expression. You need to escape them to get the literal character.

Comment: @mslowiak, my app is not generating the token

Comment: @Henry thanx for suggesting, but even after escaping characters it is still not working as expected

Comment: Can you give an example that "does not work"?

Comment: @Henry "8c4833cc-23ab-4e1b-8461-57a859b48fa1" for this it should say as not jwt token. & "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c" as jwt

Comment: The second `^` symbol in the regexp seems to be invalid

Comment: @AlexRudenko i also tried with "^[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\\.?[A-Za-z0-9-_.+/=]*$", but didn't work. please correct the regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can follow alternative approach.
A JWT token has three parts.Header info containing type and algorithm, payload and signature. Header and Body part is Base64 Encoded. If you decode the header part you will token type.

From your example token is `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MTYyMzkwMjJ9tbD.epxpstvGdW8TC3G8zg4B6rUYAOvfzdceoH48wgRQ`

So header part is eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
After decode you will get `{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}`
From decoded value you can determine whether it is a jwt token or not

Answer (score 5):

I think we can check the token is jwt or not in this way:

- Check if the jwt can be splitted by "." in to three parts (header, payload, signature)
- Check the header, if it can be base64-decoded
- Check the token type in the decoded header, if it is jwt

> The header typically consists of two parts: the type of the
> token, which is JWT, and the signing algorithm being used, such as
> HMAC SHA256 or RSA.
>
> For example:
>
> {   "alg": "HS256",   "typ": "JWT" } Then, this JSON is Base64Url
> encoded to form the first part of the JWT.

https://jwt.io/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

The [following regexp](https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyydwm0ynr) seems to be working:

```
    String pattern = "^[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9-_.+/=]*$";
```

Answer (score 0):

This regexp should work:

```
String pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9\\-_=]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9\\-_=]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9\\-_.+/=]+)?$";
```